# Autowiring clock across projects causes 'No Such Bean found' exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, autowired

My project is setup as below.

[image]

As the diagram depicts, I have a helper project (with 2 @Autowired clocks), and my main project with 1 @Autowired clock. All the three clocks mean the same object.

When I start up the application, I get the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'helper2': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'clock'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'java.time.Clock' available: expected at least
>   1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]    Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'java.time.Clock' available: expected at least
>   1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]

Comment: How do you provide your beans definition? Through .xml file? As I see you have `MainConfig.class` where the `@Bean` is defined, but in that case, that class needs to be marked as `@Configuration`.

Comment: In Main Config, you are defining bean of type clock and autowiring as a class member. Why do you need @autowired clock there?

Comment: You have a circular dependency.

Comment: Thankyou Devdio. I am not using xml file. I have marked my MainConfig with @Configuration, but I get the same error.

Comment: Thankyou for your response Himanshu. I have removed the Autowired from the MainConfig.
The MainConfig has only the method, 
@Bean
public Clock getClock() {
return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
}

Helper2 and Helper3 have the Autowired Clock clock annotation.

Still the same error though.

Comment: Thankyou for your response chrylis. How do I remove this circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Spring expects a Bean definition of an implementation of `java.time.Clock` in order to be able to autowire it. Since you already expose the return value of `Clock.systemDefaultZone` as a `@Bean`, the only thing you have to do is add `@Configuration` to your `MainConfig.java` and make sure `MainConfig` is properly picked up by Spring, either via `@ComponentScan` or `@Import`.

Comment: Thankyou. I have added the 'Configuration' annotation to the MainConfig. I still get the same error.

To be noted, the "Bean not found" exception comes in Helper2 class of dependency project that is imported into the main project, not in the MainConfig class. 

I will not be able to 'import' or 'ComponentScan' the MainConfig class into the dependency project since it will create a cyclic dependency. 

Is there any other way of fixing the code?

Comment: There's no need for a cyclic compile-time dependency - assuming your `@SpringBootApplication` is also in your "main Spring Boot application". Just add 
`@Import(MainConfig.class)` to the class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Thankyou ptikobj, I need 'clock' in classes Helper2 and Helper3. Should I remove the @Autowired Clock declaration in these 2 classes? How will I get access to clock from MainConfig then?

Comment: There's no need to remove the `@Autowired Clock` from `Helper2` and `Helper3`.  Spring's Bean Container is a runtime-concept and as such does not care whether `Helper2` and `Helper3` have compile-time access to `MainConfig`.
You have to make sure though that `Helper1`, `Helper2`, `Helper3` and `MainConfig` are in the same Spring Application Context which they are if you didn't change any of Spring Boot's defaults.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot autowire java.time.Clock since it isn't a Spring component. A spring component is a class that's considered for auto-detection.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html

I was editing my response but it seems like @ptikobj has already answered the question in a good way. I'd add to that, that adding `@SpringBootConfiguration` to the class instead of just `@Configuration` will handle the componentscan already, so there will be no need for that.

Comment: That answer does not seem to be comprehensive enough, please elaborate to help OP, if you're willing to post answers.